# Detect if a newly created model has changed attributes

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Say you have a /new route, and the router creates a new instance of your model.

Your model's properties are bound to some input fields on the page.

I want to be able to detect if the new model has changed since it's instantiation.

`model.get('hasDirtyAttributes')` unfortunately reports true for new instances, because it has not been saved yet.

I thought to try `model.get('hasDirtyAttributes') && model.get('dirtyType') === 'updated'` but dirtyType is still `created` until you do the first save.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `model.changedAttributes()` and see if it's empty ([docs](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/models/working-with-records/)), but you can't observe it.  Ex -

```
Object.keys(this.get('model').changedAttributes()).length > 0
```

I am not aware of a general attribute that you could observe in this case.  You would have to observe a specified list of attributes.

*or* you could override `set` on your model and have it set a value -

```
set: (key, value) ->
    @attributeHasChanged = true
    @_super(key, value)
```

Comment: Yep. Since `changedAttributes()` returns an object, I ended up with `Ember.keys(this.get('model').changedAttributes()).length > 0`

Comment: Great!  Please accept the answer if it solved the problem

Comment: I will leave it open slightly longer to allow anyone else to answer, and then accept. Can you edit your answer to include the snippet I pasted?  

Also, since Ember.keys is deprecated, it should be Object.keys, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

You could create a computed property on that model which would depend on any declared attribute and would return true if any of attributes differs from it's initial value, otherways false.

For better performance you could only compute this property if `model.get('isNew') === true`.